# Split text file by word ( character) count

Tags: text, ascii

In short: How to split 10000 word TXT file into 100 word TXT file each.
I am trying to split a large text file by word count.
The best option so far i can find is this software (Gsplit), but it's only have option to split by line.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxRO4.jpg)

This app have option to split by pattern.
Exp for split by line is: "0x0D0x0A".
So is there any pattern to split the text file by word count ( by this Gsplit app or another way) ?

Comment: Split by word count or character count? Or by either? Is each split segment to go into speparate smaller files or into an array (or collection)?

Comment: @Abra Its my ignorance, cause i really have no idea  of how to code or any coding language.

Comment: @DevilsHnd I want to split by word count and each split segment go to separate smaller files, thank for your clearing

Comment: So the file you want to split is an ASCII text file?

Comment: @Abra - the file is a windows text file

Comment: I have written a small java [_Swing_] app that does this. Let me know if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged "java" with your question, here is a simple java code to count the number of words by splitting by spaces.

```
public class Splitting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputLines = "This class is for split words by spaces and count the number of words"; 
        String[] words = inputLines.split(" "); 
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
        System.out.println("No of words: "+words.length);   }
}
```

output:

```
[This, class, is, for, split, words, by, spaces, and, count, the, number, of, words]
No of words: 14
```

Hope this would help somehow!

Comment: Thank mate, but this is not what i am looking for